# How do I make a cell return a value based on the characters.?

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, formulas

I have a cell that I want to use and IF statement to tell return information based on characters in the cell. I.E the cell has =M=WRFY, I want the statement to give me a start time based on the day within. I used this formula for the first set and it worked but for the next day it fails.

=IF(LEFT(I44,1)="S",H44,"")

I've tried entering the 2 where the 1 is to make it look at character 2 but its not working. Help!!

[image: 1]]

Comment: Is this question about Excel? If so, please tag it accordingly.

Comment: I am using excel, I added an image of what I'm trying to do. So I have each day of the week lined out and the column with ==TWRFY represent a pattern. I want a formula in the the Sun Start column that will reference the start time only if there is an S in the pattern. Same for Mon, Tues, an so on. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: thank you, after this change your question is much easier to understand.

Comment: Use MID instead. `MID(I44,2,1)`,  `MID(I44,3,1)`, etc. 2 and 3 here are the position of the character in the text, the last 1 means to get only 1 character.

Comment: you can use MID from the beginning to the end if you want. There are actually a number of different functions that would do the job. I'll post another in a sec, in the meantime check this out: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Text-functions-reference-cccd86ad-547d-4ea9-a065-7bb697c2a56e

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `Mid` or `Left` or `Right`you need to specify a position in the string, which isn't a big deal in this case since it's not changing.  Either way I prefer to use `FIND`, which returns either a number (the position that the string1 was found in string2, or else an Error if it's not found.

The location is irrelevant in this case so this just checks if there's an error.  If so, it wasn't found (and we get a `""` blank string); if not, it was found (and returns the value of cell H44).

```
=IF(ISERROR(FIND("S",$E6)),"",H44)
```

You said something about it only working for a few cells.  If you're copying the formula to other cells but want to keep on referring to column "E" then putting a `$` in front of `E` keeps that letter "locked in" whereever you copy it.

([Reference](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Text-functions-reference-cccd86ad-547d-4ea9-a065-7bb697c2a56e))

---

## Splitting up a cell

A combination of the `Find`, `Left`, `Right`, and `Len` functions will handle many common tasks like splitting a single text value `2:30 PM-3:30 PM` into two cells.

We already know that `Find` will locate one string inside another, like `FIND("-",A2)` would return **8** in this example.  And, we know that Left returns characters from the left side of a string.

We don't want the first 8 because that would include the "-" that was "found". So, we'll subtract one.  Assuming your text to split is in cell A2, this place this formula where you want the left part of the string:

```
=LEFT(A2,FIND("-",A2)-1)
```

and we know `Right` returns the right-side number of characters we specify.  `Len` will tell us the total length of the string.  Therefore, total length minus the left part that we don't want in *this* part...

Place this formula where you want to right part of the string:

```
=RIGHT(A2,LEN(A2)-FIND("-",A2))
```

---

### Basic text functions worth learning

A little bit of homework for you.  Once you start practicing with functions they will make a lot more sense, and "nesting" (combining) them will become second nature!  :-)

- [**CHAR**](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/CHAR-function-bbd249c8-b36e-4a91-8017-1c133f9b837a)  :  *Returns the character specified by the code number*
- [**CLEAN**](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/CLEAN-function-26f3d7c5-475f-4a9c-90e5-4b8ba987ba41)  :  *Removes all nonprintable characters from text*
- [**CODE**](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/CODE-function-c32b692b-2ed0-4a04-bdd9-75640144b928)  :  *Returns a numeric code for the first character in a text string*
- [**CONCATENATE**](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/CONCATENATE-function-8f8ae884-2ca8-4f7a-b093-75d702bea31d)  :  *Joins several text items into one text item*
- [**FIND**](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/FIND-FINDB-functions-c7912941-af2a-4bdf-a553-d0d89b0a0628)  :  *Finds one text value within another (case-sensitive)*
- [**LEFT**](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/LEFT-LEFTB-functions-9203d2d2-7960-479b-84c6-1ea52b99640c)  :  *Returns the leftmost characters from a text value*
- [**LEN**](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/LEN-LENB-functions-29236f94-cedc-429d-affd-b5e33d2c67cb)  :  *Returns the number of characters in a text string*
- [**LOWER**](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/LOWER-function-3f21df02-a80c-44b2-afaf-81358f9fdeb4)  :  *Converts text to lowercase*
- [**MID**](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/MID-MIDB-functions-d5f9e25c-d7d6-472e-b568-4ecb12433028)  :  *Returns a specific number of characters from a text string starting at the position you specify*
- [**PROPER**](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/PROPER-function-52a5a283-e8b2-49be-8506-b2887b889f94)  :  *Capitalizes the first letter in each word of a text value*
- [**REPLACE**](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/REPLACE-REPLACEB-functions-8d799074-2425-4a8a-84bc-82472868878a)  :  *Replaces characters within text*
- [**REPT**](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/REPT-function-04c4d778-e712-43b4-9c15-d656582bb061)  :  *Repeats text a given number of times*
- [**RIGHT**](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/RIGHT-RIGHTB-functions-240267ee-9afa-4639-a02b-f19e1786cf2f)  :  *Returns the rightmost characters from a text value*
- [**SEARCH**](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SEARCH-SEARCHB-functions-9ab04538-0e55-4719-a72e-b6f54513b495)  :  *Finds one text value within another (not case-sensitive)*
- [**SUBSTITUTE**](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUBSTITUTE-function-6434944e-a904-4336-a9b0-1e58df3bc332)  :  *Substitutes new text for old text in a text string*
- [**TEXT**](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/TEXT-function-20d5ac4d-7b94-49fd-bb38-93d29371225c)  :  *Formats a number and converts it to text*
- [**TRIM**](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/TRIM-function-410388fa-c5df-49c6-b16c-9e5630b479f9)  :  *Removes spaces from text*
- [**UPPER**](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/UPPER-function-c11f29b3-d1a3-4537-8df6-04d0049963d6)  :  *Converts text to uppercase*
- [**VALUE**](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/VALUE-function-257d0108-07dc-437d-ae1c-bc2d3953d8c2)  :  *Converts a text argument to a number*

([Source](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Text-functions-reference-cccd86ad-547d-4ea9-a065-7bb697c2a56e))

Also valuable:  **[Excel Functions Listed By Category](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Excel-functions-by-category-5f91f4e9-7b42-46d2-9bd1-63f26a86c0eb)**

Comment: Thank you so much. One last question. Is there a formula that can give me the start and stop times separately from the cell listed like this. 2:30 PM-3:30 PM

Comment: You're welcome, glad to help (even if I'm a smartass occasionally, lol)...  So you want to split `2:30 PM-3:30 PM` into two cells?

Comment: I added formulas for splitting cells to my answer (above).  If my response helped you find the solution to your issue, you can "accept" the answer with the checkmark next to the Answer (then I earn rep.)  You also might want to check out the [tour] as well as [ask] and [mcve].  Good luck!